# How can I fix this closure within a list function?

Tags: javascript, closures, anonymous-function

This [very good Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) gives an example of how closures can work counter intuitively when returning anonymous functions within a list.

```
function buildList(list) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var item = 'item' + i;
        result.push( function() {alert(item + ' ' + list[i])} );
    }
    return result;
}

function testList() {
    var fnlist = buildList([1,2,3]);
    // Using j only to help prevent confusion -- could use i.
    for (var j = 0; j < fnlist.length; j++) {
        fnlist[j]();
    }
}
```

This code will return:

```
item2 undefined
item2 undefined
item2 undefined
```

My question is - how would you modify this code so that it returns the result we're expecting?

```
item0 1
item1 2
item2 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [**IIFE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript) in the `for` loop in `buildList` and pass in the `i`.

This will ensure that the `i` passed in will remain enclosed in the `IIFE` closure and will not be changed by the `i` in the `for` loop

```js
function buildList(list) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    //the IIFE
    (function(i) {
      var item = 'item' + i;
      result.push(function() {
        console.log(item + ' ' + list[i])
      });
    })(i);
  }
  return result;
}

function testList() {
  var fnlist = buildList([1, 2, 3]);
  // Using j only to help prevent confusion -- could use i.
  for (var j = 0; j < fnlist.length; j++) {
    fnlist[j]();
  }
}

testList();
```

Comment: Thanks heaps. It looks like the link you posted explains it well. :)